# adjust_text's only_move parameter not working for overlapping last value outside of the plot area?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been trying to use the [`adjustText`](https://adjusttext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library to adjust two plot annotation that were overlapping with each other. I'm doing something like that:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from adjustText import adjust_text
import numpy as np

foo = np.linspace(1, 100,  1000)
bar = np.linspace(1, 100.1, 1000)
x = np.linspace(0,1,1000)

w, h = plt.figaspect(9/16) 
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(w, h), dpi=300, frameon=False)
ax = plt.gca()

plt.xlim(x[0], x[-1])

ax.plot(x, foo, label='Foo', color='b')
plt.annotate(f'{foo[-1]}',
         xy = (1, foo[-1]),
         xytext=(8, 0), 
         xycoords=('axes fraction', 'data'),
         textcoords='offset points',
         color='b'
        )

ax.plot(x, bar, label='Bar', color='orange')
plt.annotate(f'{bar[-1]}',
         xy = (1, bar[-1]),
         xytext=(8, 0), 
         xycoords=('axes fraction', 'data'),
         textcoords='offset points',
         color='orange'
        )
```

Which results in an figure with overlapping annotations

[image: Overlapping annotations]

Then I tried to use the `adjust_text` function and added the following lines of code to the original block:

```
annotations = [child for child in ax.get_children() if isinstance(child, matplotlib.text.Annotation)]
adjust_text(annotations,
            only_move={'points':'xy', 'text':'y', 'objects':'xy'},
            autoalign='y',
           )
```

And then the texts stopped overlapping with each other, but started to overlap with the lines of the plot. What am I doing wrong?

[image: New image]

Comment: Your code is correct. If you want to move the text in the x-axis, you can use the following code. `adjust_text(annotations, only_move={'points':'xy', 'text':'x', 'objects':'xy'},autoalign='x',)`

Comment: I don't want to move the texts in the x-axis. I want to move them in the y-axis

Comment: Is your code already moving in the y-axis?
You need a specific y-axis position.

Comment: It's moving in both axis. I passed the only_move dict to restrain the movement in the x-axis, but the text moved in the x-axis anyway. My question is about any mistakes I've possibly made while trying to restrain the movement for only the y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the adjustText library, so I tried various parameters and did not get the expected results. However, autoalign='y' did have an effect. Then I adjusted the position on the matplotlib side.

```
ax.plot(x, foo, label='Foo', color='b')
plt.annotate(f'{foo[-1]}',
         xy = (1, foo[-1]),
         xytext=(20, 0), 
         xycoords=('axes fraction','data'),
         textcoords='offset points',
         color='b'
        )

ax.plot(x, bar, label='Bar', color='orange')
plt.annotate(f'{bar[-1]}',
         xy = (1, bar[-1]),
         xytext=(20, 0), 
         xycoords=('axes fraction','data'),
         textcoords='offset points',
         color='orange'
        )

annotations = [child for child in ax.get_children() if isinstance(child, matplotlib.text.Annotation)]
adjust_text(annotations,
            autoalign='y'
           )
```

[image]